# How to simplify converting several column attributes and recoding multiple columns?

Tags: r, simplify

I have several lines of codes that I'm figuring out how to simplify. My attempts to do so have resulted in errors. Below is a small section of the lines of code:

```
SS_data$Cope1 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope1)
SS_data$Cope2 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope2)
SS_data$Cope3 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope3)
SS_data$Cope4 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope4)
SS_data$Cope5 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope5)
SS_data$Cope6 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope6)
SS_data$Cope7 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope7)
SS_data$Cope8 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope8)
SS_data$Cope9 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope9)
SS_data$Cope10 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope10)
SS_data$Cope11 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope11)
SS_data$Cope12 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope12)
SS_data$Cope13 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope13)
SS_data$Cope14 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope14)
SS_data$Cope15 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope15)
SS_data$Cope16 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope16)
SS_data$Cope17 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope17)
SS_data$Cope18 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope18)
SS_data$Cope19 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope19)
SS_data$Cope20 <- as.numeric(SS_data$Cope20)
```

I'm also trying to simplify the codes below. I end up recoding for each variable and I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify this as well.

```
WHOQOL16[WHOQOL16 == "Very dissatisfied"] <- 1
WHOQOL16[WHOQOL16 == "Dissatisfied"] <- 2
WHOQOL16[WHOQOL16 == "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied"] <- 3
WHOQOL16[WHOQOL16 == "Satisfied"] <- 4
WHOQOL16[WHOQOL16 == "Very satisfied"] <- 5
              
WHOQOL17[WHOQOL17 == "Very dissatisfied"] <- 1
WHOQOL17[WHOQOL17 == "Dissatisfied"] <- 2
WHOQOL17[WHOQOL17 == "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied"] <- 3
WHOQOL17[WHOQOL17 == "Satisfied"] <- 4
WHOQOL17[WHOQOL17 == "Very satisfied"] <- 5
              
WHOQOL18[WHOQOL18 == "Very dissatisfied"] <- 1
WHOQOL18[WHOQOL18 == "Dissatisfied"] <- 2
WHOQOL18[WHOQOL18 == "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied"] <- 3
WHOQOL18[WHOQOL18 == "Satisfied"] <- 4
WHOQOL18[WHOQOL18 == "Very satisfied"] <- 5
              
WHOQOL19[WHOQOL19 == "Very dissatisfied"] <- 1
WHOQOL19[WHOQOL19 == "Dissatisfied"] <- 2
WHOQOL19[WHOQOL19 == "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied"] <- 3
WHOQOL19[WHOQOL19 == "Satisfied"] <- 4
WHOQOL19[WHOQOL19 == "Very satisfied"] <- 5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include your data.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: In `dplyr`, you can use `SS_data %>% mutate(across(starts_with('Cope'), as.numeric))` to turn all columns which start with `'Cope'` to numeric. For the second part are `WHOQOL16`, `WHOQOL17` are separate vectors in your global environment?

Comment: Thank you. As for WHOQOL16, WHOQOL17, not necessarily. Those are separate columns.

Comment: I tried SS_data %>% mutate(across(starts_with('Cope'), as.numeric)) and, unfortunately, it still remains as character. I have the dplyr installed and loaded from the library. It's also not giving any error, so I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot it. The code would run, but when I check the structure, it still remains as character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dplyr` you can use `across` function to apply same function to multiple columns.

We change columns that start with `"Cope"` to numeric and recode the columns which start with `"WHOQOL"`.

```
library(dplyr)

SS_data_new <- SS_data %>% 
                    mutate(across(starts_with('Cope'), as.numeric), 
                           across(starts_with('WHOQOL'), 
                           ~recode(., "Very dissatisfied" = 1, 
                                       "Dissatisfied" = 2, 
                                       "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied" = 3, 
                                       "Satisfied" = 4, 
                                       "Very satisfied" = 5)))
SS_data_new
#  Cope1 Cope2 WHOQOL
#1     1     4      1
#2     2     5      1
#3     3     6      4
str(SS_data_new)
#data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Cope1 : num  1 2 3
# $ Cope2 : num  4 5 6
# $ WHOQOL: num  1 1 4
```

**data**

```
SS_data <- data.frame(Cope1 = c('1', '2', '3'), Cope2 = c('4', '5', '6'), 
           WHOQOL = c("Very dissatisfied", "Very dissatisfied", "Satisfied"))
```

Comment: I used the coding as you have shown. The code ran, but when I checked the structure, the attribute is still character and not numeric. And the WHOQOL columns were not recoded and remained the same. Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: you need to assign the data back to a new or same variable. I have assigned it back to `SS_data_new` so check the structure of `SS_data_new` with `str(SS_data_new)`.

Comment: Thank you. I did do that initially and it still shows as character. (The code seems very straightforward and not quite sure why it's not working as intended.)

Comment: Do you have the same column names as shown here in your real data?

Comment: Yes, I do. The column names are the same.

Comment: Does it return you any error/warning message? Note that `across` is a new function introduced in `dplyr` 1.0.0

Comment: No error at all. The code still runs. Just that when I check the structure after running the code, it still shows as character.

Comment: I just created a small example and it seems to work for me , see updated answer. Maybe you need to share your data similarly where we can reproduce the error from our end.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Jarhed Were you able to figure out the issue. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Questions posted to the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag on SO should include reproducible data but I have done it for
you this time in the Note at the end.

The following uses only base R.

First make a copy of `DF` in `DF2` in case you want to run the code again from scratch since the code will overwrite `DF2`.

Next convert columns 1 and 2 to numeric and convert X, Y and Z in columns 3 and 4 to 1, 2 and 3.  If non-numeric entries appear in columns 1 or 2 or entries that are not X, Y or Z appear in columns 3 or 4 then NA will be assigned to those entries.  (Alternately for the second line of code there exists a `recode` function in the dplyr package and a different `recode` function having the same purpose in the car package.)

The column numbers are obvious in this example but if they are not in your data use expressions like `grep("Cope", names(DF))` to get them.

```
DF2 <- DF
DF2[1:2] <- lapply(DF2[1:2], as.numeric)
DF2[3:4] <- lapply(DF2[3:4], match, c("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

giving the following where the warning is just to let you know that it encountered a value that could not be converted to numeric so it converted it to NA.

```
> DF2
Warning message:
In lapply(DF[1:2], as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
   A  B  C  D
1  1 11  1  1
2 NA 12  2 NA
3  3 13 NA  3
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(A = c("1", "x", "3"), B = c("11", "12", "13"),
  C = c("X", "Y", "a"), D = c("X", NA, "Z"))
```